# Linked List breaks after a few iterations

Tags: java, linked-list

Can someone please see if there is an error in my code? I have looked for a while, and tried tweaking things but I just can't get it working.

```
while(current != null)
{
  comparisons++;
  String currentWord = current.getWord();

  if(currentWord.equals(word))
  {
    int count = current.getCount();
    count++;
    current.setCount(count);
    isFound = true;
    total++;
    LLNode next = current.getLink();
    previous.setLink(next);
    current.setLink(top);
    top = current;
  }
  else
  {
    previous = current;
    current = current.getLink();
  }
}
```

Okay so this code runs but doesn't give me an error code. It simply gets stuck in an infinite loop as soon as it finds the word it needs. The entire code is to read the words from hamlet and add them into a linked list. each time a word is already in the list we increment it's counter and move that link to the beginning of the linked list. If I follow it in debug mode, it functions properly for about 12 words or so, then just stops in an infinite loop with the word "i" and increments indefinately. I'm very confused.

Comment: How does it break?  What is the exact error/stack trace?

Comment: Is there an error you can show? You might also need to provide more code, for example what does getLink() do?

Comment: Also the problem could be in your linked list implementation...

Comment: What error are you getting? What line of this snippet is it on? Are you sure that your variables are what they should be when this snippet runs? Try to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: What is your code trying to do?

Comment: Where are you trying to move the link to the beginning of linked list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to tell exactly what the code you have posted is intended to do. I'm guessing that the ideas is that it takes a new word and adds it to the list or increments the counter if it is already there. If that's the case then you have quite a few errors in your code.

1. you aren't adding a new node if the word isn't found
2. you aren't moving to the next node if the current node doesn't match the word
3. you aren't exiting your loop after incrementing the counter and moving the node to the head of the list

I'll use pseudo code here and leave you to implement the details - let me know if the meaning isn't obvious.

```
Node current = top;
boolean found = false;
boolean added = false;
while (!(found || added)) {
    if (current matches word) {
        increment current.count and move to top of list;
        found = true;
    } else if (current.getLink() == null) {
        make new node using word, count 1, link null;
        current.setLink(new node);
        added = true;
    } else {
        current = current.getLink();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you arent changing current after you find the word, it will never get a nil link and it will always have currentWord.equals(word) return true
Try:

```
if(currentWord.equals(word))
  {
    int count = current.getCount();
    count++;
    current.setCount(count);
    isFound = true;
    total++;
    LLNode next = current.getLink();
    previous.setLink(next);
    current.setLink(top);
    top = current;
    current = next; //add this line
  }
  else
  {
    previous = current;
    current = current.getLink();
  }
```

Comment: that still doesn't help. so the code exits the loop and is called again from my main method to add the next word to the list.